# Update not working in SQL Server CE C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I am trying to create an update WINFORM, the back story is the form will get info from a dataGridView when the user double clicks on the specific GUID.

My issue is that when the user inputs information and clicks the submit button I am getting the error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 1, Token
>   line offset = 66, Token in error = Desc].

This may be a simple error that I am just over looking but any help is appreciated. The code for the button click is:

```
private void sbmtChng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.CurricularChangeTrackerConnectionString;

        using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                string cmdString = "UPDATE Changes SET "
                     + "ProgramCode=@ProgramCode,CourseNum=@CourseNum,Desc=@Desc,ScreenCom=@ScreenCom,PECAprv=@PECAprv,SenAprv=@SenAprv,EffDte=@EffDte,APG=@APG,Analysis=@Analysis,Matrix=@Matrix,DESE=@DESE"
                     + " WHERE Code_ID=@Code_ID";

                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmdString, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code_ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Code_ID;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgramCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PrgmCode;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseNum", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CrseLbl.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ChngDes.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScreenCom", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = scrnCmtDte.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PECAprv", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pecAprDte.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SenAprv", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = senAprvDateTimePicker.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EffDte", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = effDte.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APG", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = checkBox5.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Analysis", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = checkBox6.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Matrix", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = checkBox7.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESE", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = checkBox8.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();

                    /*this.Controls.Clear();
                    this.InitializeComponent();
                    this.Close();
                    */
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like there's an error in your query. Try displaying the cmd.CommandText (via a messagebox or console or debugging) and see what text you are passing to the command. Most likely you've forgotten a comma or something. The Desc field seems to be the culprit, I'd focus my attention there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DESC` is a reserved keyword. Rename the column (preferable) or change the code to surround the column name in square brackets:

```
+ "ProgramCode=@ProgramCode,CourseNum=@CourseNum,[Desc]=@Desc,..."
// ----------------------------------------------^----^
```